# Highscore not updating c#

Tags: c#

I have a score and high score script that doesn't seem to be working there are no errors but the high score doesn't update when the player dies.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class OnGui2D : MonoBehaviour
{    
     public static OnGui2D OG2D;
     public static int score;
     int hScore;
     Text sText;
     Text hText;
     // Use this for initialization

     void Start () {
         OG2D = this;
         score = 0;
         hScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("HighScore1", 0);
         sText = GameObject.Find ("sText").GetComponent<Text> ();
         hText = GameObject.Find ("sText").GetComponent<Text> ();

     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {

         sText.text = ("" + (score + 0));
         hText.text = ("" + hScore);

     }
     void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) 
     {
         if (col.gameObject.tag == "Coin") {

             score = score + 1;

         } else if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {

             OnGui2D.OG2D.CheckHighScore();


         }
     }

     public void CheckHighScore(){

         if ((score + 0) > hScore) {

             Debug.Log ("Saving highscore");
             PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("HighScore1", (score + 0));             
         }     
     }         
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your code... can you reduce it to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and/or show a failing test case?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to GET the int and not set it? And why do you always add zero?

```
     public void CheckHighScore(){

     if ((score + 0) > hScore) {

         Debug.Log ("Saving highscore");
         PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("HighScore1", (score + 0));             
     }     
 }
```

->

```
     public void CheckHighScore(){

     if ((score + 0) > hScore) {

         Debug.Log ("Saving highscore");
         PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("HighScore1", (score + 0));             
     }     
 }
```